How many people can Gaza support after the last six months of fighting?

The Gaza Strip is not a very big place. The area of the Gaza Strip is about 139 square miles. This includes a significant amount of farmland and desert open space. It is about twice as wide and twice as long as Manhattan and is similarly densely populated. It is smaller geographically than most U.S. counties; it is smaller than four U.S. survey townships.
As of October 6, 2023, there were about 2.3 million Gazans. Just under half of Gazans are children (the median age there is 19 years old). This is more than 16,500 people per square mile including land that had no residents six months ago, which is a very high level of urban density.
Virtually all of Gaza's ordinary businesses have been interrupted. The vast majority of adults in Gaza are unemployed, or at least not employed in the work that they were employed in six months ago. Gaza has gone six months with essentially no external trade except meager aid shipments. The inventory of a large share of its wholesale and retail businesses has been ruined.
Most Gazans are internally displaced and those who aren't are swamped with displaced people living in tents (or less) all around them. It has no local sources of fuel, and vastly insufficient sources of local food or water to support 2.3 million people.
Gaza's few major roads need major work to be passable for civilian vehicles, and they are littered with burnt out and destroyed vehicles. Most vehicles that aren't destroyed right now aren't functional because they have no fuel.
Gaza City, where most Gazans lived six months ago, is mostly rubble. Hundred of thousands of apartments, many of the hospitals, a large share of all municipal offices, thousands of retail stores and office buildings, countless legitimate utility tunnels (in addition to its illicit Hamas tunnels designed to support military actions), the electrical grid, its telecommunications networks, many water mains, and more have been destroyed.
At this point, for most of Gaza City, the only safe option is to demolish what is left and start over from scratch. This doesn't happen over night. It would take many years to rebuild all of what has been destroyed in the last six months, even with peace and unlimited financing. And, rebuilding Gaza would be a high risk, low return investment opportunity (in a place also rife with corruption) for any private investor.
Given all that has happened in the last six months, how many people could Gaza provide a home to, in remotely tolerable conditions, with perhaps six months of rebuilding, if the fighting stopped tomorrow, some form of local government administration tolerable to Israel and the Gazans was put in place, and significant international reconstruction aid was provided?
How much would that cost?

It certainly depends on who's willing to fund what reconstruction and what is Israel willing to allow in in terms building materials etc. Many parts of Syria are still rubble etc. (Yes, I'm aware there was also an earthquake.)

@thegodsfromengineering I'm asking in terms of a best case scenario in hopes of putting a lower bound on the number of Gazans that it can't support in the near future, no matter what.

You write: "This includes a significant amount of farmland and desert open space. It is about twice as wide and twice as long as Manhattan and is similarly densely populated." which sounds like a contradiction. There is/was some farmland and open space but not very much of it. Also comparing to Manhattan is misleading because Manhattan is covered with 50 and 100 story sky scrapers whereas the Gaza strip had mostly 3 to at most 10 story buildings. Comparing to virtually any other major city is more accurate.

high risk, low return investment opportunity  True, but that may be the wrong way to look at it.  Assume for a second that something like a reasonable, long term, no Hamas, two state solution materializes at some point.  Assume furthermore that Israel has no say on the area, except for (very) strong security enforcement guarantees.  The amount of money that has been used in waging these wars is staggering.  The international community could finance quite the Marshall Plan, just to make this problem go away.  It's certainly not an investment, but it might be a worthwhile expense.

And... keep in mind that the food situation was dire and heavily aid dependent before 10/7 already and living conditions abysmal so we are not talking about repairing Beverly Hills back to Beverly Hills standards after an earthquake.  That said, I don't see how this Q can be answered with anything but opinions at this point in time.

@quarague It isn't really a contradiction. The size is just a comparison of total geographic dimensions. The population density is just crude total population per  unit of total land area. Eyeballing it, due to setbacks from the wall and farmland, I'd guess that 1/3 to 1/2 of the land in Gaza is farmland and desert open space - the map in the question illustrates the point. Manhattan has 72,918 residents per square mile; Gaza has 16,500 per square mile. 1,000 per square mile is roughly  the cutoff for urban. Both are high in population density relative to that.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The point with respect to it being a high risk, low return investment opportunity is that private sector investors motivated purely by profit probably wouldn't make that investment. They'd either be non-economically motivated private sector investments motivated in part by a desire to make Palestinian lives better despite having more profitable alternatives available, or NGO/governmental investors who, as you say, see it as a worthwhile foreign policy/human rights expenditure.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "we are not talking about repairing Beverly Hill" which is why I put the bolded caveat remotely tolerable conditions" into the question. I think that there are probably sufficient facts out there to go beyond opinion, primarily based upon estimates of the share of housing stock destroyed and damage to other infrastructure with some sort of background from, e.g., natural disasters, on how long it takes to rebuild after mass destruction. I don't have those competencies to a great degree, but someone out there probably does.

As you probably know, and most lamentably, reconstruction is not the intention of the Israeli government

@PeteW The point is not what is intended by someone. The point is to explore what the range of possible viable options is given things that have already been irrevocably done. If the answer is that, for example, best case scenario, Gaza only has a carrying capacity of one million people for the foreseeable future, any solution needs to figure out what should be done about the 1.3 million people to whom Gaza can no longer provide a place to live. This matters for any resolution and if Gaza can, e.g.,  support 2.2 million v. 1 million, the options to resolve the situation are different.

Ok, it's worth documenting. At the moment, with so much of potable water and sanitation infrastructure destroyed, depowered, or inaccessible, the figure is probably even lower than a million. Here's a recently dated search result: https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/press-release/2024/04/02/joint-world-bank-un-report-assesses-damage-to-gaza-s-infrastructure ... the report itself: https://thedocs.worldbank.org/en/doc/14e309cd34e04e40b90eb19afa7b5d15-0280012024/original/Gaza-Interim-Damage-Assessment-032924-Final.pdf

From the point of view of financial cost of reconstruction, you'll see from that report it's mostly housing. But from the point of view of making the place habitable under even refugee-camp conditions (eg mass of trailers or something like that), it's the lack of water, sanitation, medicine, energy, and food. From the point of view of viability of a solution..... I can't think of anything good to say, I'm sorry. At the end of the day, the Israeli government does not want Palestinians there, and they have a powerful ally in Washington (notwithstanding occasional token verbal concessions).

@PeteW To be clear, I'm not endorsing what has already happened as good or bad. I am simply trying to figure out what the facts are on the ground in order to provide a shared factual foundation for anyone trying to figure out what makes sense to do now. While there is more than one possible solution, it makes no sense to give too much attention to options that are for all practical purposes impossible due to the physical realities of what it takes for people to physically survive.

Update: "After a year, the UN estimates that a total of 42m tonnes of rubble clutter the Strip, to clear and rebuilt which might take 80 years, and cost over $80bn." Lucy Swan, Tural Ahmedzade, Harvey Symons, How a year of war laid waste the Gaza Strip – visualised The Guardian 10 October 2024. https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/oct/10/how-a-year-of-war-laid-waste-the-gaza-strip-visualised


how many people could Gaza provide a home to, in remotely tolerable conditions, with perhaps six months of rebuilding

Frame challenge: how is the question even relevant if they can't escape the zone?
In 2021 about 40% of Gazans said they considered leaving it. That number is surely higher now. But it doesn't matter. The powers that be, meaning collectively the other countries don't give them a way out. (The percentage doesn't appear implausible to me--it was similar in Syria polls. And many Syrians did flee--more than half of the population was at least internally displaced, but only about a quarter over their borders. But the Syrians had the physical possibility to leave, although that has become increasingly difficult for them too.)
So, the Gazans can [just] move their tents around, as Netanyahu put it.
FWTW, it's been mentioned in one comment that the World Bank estimates it would take $18.5 billion to rebuild Gaza. Egypt's president, on the other hand, estimated that it would take $90 billion. Whether there's some political agenda behind those discrepancies, or just an honest difference in methodology/assumptions, I cannot quite say right now.

I suppose the relevance is to have a clear idea of the magnitude of the irreversible harm that is now "baked in". To a badly jaded observer like me, it's near total. At the risk of speculating, I have to figure Egypt may well be pushed hard to let them enter at some point, after the body count becomes intolerable for third parties, and the pressure on the Gazan population is so intense that practically nobody would stay. If such a thing happened, I doubt the current Israeli government would object.

I think the Q is asking for a more charitable assessment of the current moment, that presumes a settlement of the conflict and good faith effort to recover

"how is the question even relevant if they can't escape the zone?" Because it separates what is possible from what is impossible. Relocation of some Gazans because it is impossible for all of them to continue living in Gaza is something that could happen from a change in policy from Israel and other countries. If more than 40% of Gazans  (ca. 1 M) really want to leave, and there is someplace that would let them come (which international pressure from the U.S. and others could facilitate if it seemed necessary), many in Israel would be delighted be see them go. This could be a partial solution.

@ohwilleke: FWTW, Egypt's president says rebuilding Gaza would take $90 billion, far in excess of what the World Bank says ($18B). So, do you think he's pressuring himself there, or just trying to convince his own public to take the Gazans in? I personally think time will.

@thegodsfromengineering I appreciate the numbers. These kinds of estimates are not an exact science, and are very assumption laden. Getting two estimates that are within a factor of five of each other from two independent third-party sources isn't bad, especially when it might be possible to get even closer if one adjusted for the differing assumptions going into each estimate. Those numbers would be a good addition to your answer.

Egypt's president, on the other hand, estimated that it would take $90 billion. - Egyptian estimates are understandably higher, since they include baksheesh. Regarding people living - yes, one needs a physical possibility, but there is also the question of documents and paying the necessary fees/bribes. Those who left Gaza by now are mostly holders of foreign passports (at least Egyptian ones.)

Regarding the estimates, I wonder what 1-1.5 million people's worth of basic homes plus restoration of infrastructure and property/equipment for services would cost today in the region. The $18B would put it at $15000 a person, which seems very efficient, especially considering (as the Q points out) that it would have to be done in an expedited and surged mode of construction.

Besides that, not to belabor the obvious, most societies assign a cost to people who die, and that too may be larger than the property and equipment. Western insurance payout=millions. It takes many years of work to raise an adult, lets say 10+ years if you figure family with many kids, and don't worry much about education. The labor embodied in an economy concrete-block housing unit is order of low single digits I think. (this isn't a criticism of the Q nor this answer, just occurred to me last night as this discussion is about restoring the objects, which must be small change in comparison)

@PeteW At $5 million per life (a common figure used in the U.S. for cost-benefit analysis) and on the order of 42,000 dead, so far the toll of lost lives is about $210 billion, which is larger than property and equipment but not as dramatically as you might suspect. The bigger concern is how to prevent future deaths among those who are still living. Property damage can only get a little bit worse. Deaths can increase dramatically.
